# Javascript if box checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, field

i have this form for adding videos. Now, there's a input field for "title" and i want that to disappear if you have pressed on the checkbox "tryout". How should i do that in JS.. i use jquery.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? up voting this again.

Comment: @questzen: because there is very little detail, and no code, provided in the question. The OP is asking in a "do this for me" sort of way. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260888/javascript-if-box-checked

Comment: @Ether: agreed, but how would people learn from their mistakes, if there is no feedback given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have correct ids assigned for both fields something like this will work:

```
$('#tryout').click(function () {
    $('#title').toggle(!$(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

Comment: IMO you have to pass !($this).attr('checked') because we want to hide the element when checkbox is checked, and while using toggle, false value hides element. Second thing, we don't have to wrap this with jQuery object to get checked value. Just use this.checked.

Comment: Indeed the condition for toggle should be negated. Second thing: you don't have to do it but I prefer keeping it that way. I don't like mixing jQuery code with "pure" JS DOM operations.

Comment: I cant get this to work? It doesnt hide when i press the checkbox

Comment: Are you sure both selectors match proper elements in your page?

Comment: Yes, with: <input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="tryout" name="tryout">Tryout</input><br> when i put a check in the checkbox, nothing happends. Nothing when i remove the check too..

Comment: If you are using firefox then check in Firebug that you don't have any errors in your JS code. You could try adding an alert inside the click function and see if that code is triggered. If it's not then perhaps you didn't put it in the correct spot.

Comment: ive put it under document load and it works great now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can just write inside document.ready function.

```
$("#chkboxId").clicked(function(){
  if($(this).attr("checked"))
    $("#title").hide();
  else
    $("#title").show();
});
```

Comment: Since I believe the OP (and anyone really) will in practice want/need to have more flexible control over display, I would suggest using toggleClass('removed', $this.checked) over element style manipulation, where 'removed' is a CSS class with display:none.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="tryout" name="tryout" onclick="javascript:$('#tryout').hide();">Tryout</input>
```